# Receiving defined but never used while indeed using in another file

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am not using modules I just include my scripts in the html file.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/processhandling.js"></script>
```

I call the functions in the html or in other scripts but the linter says `'aodv_clear_statistics' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars` 
Because I don't call it in the same file or even call in the same file but
inside a string

```
<button type="submit" class="aodvResetButtonAll" onclick="aodv_clear_statistics()">Clear The Table</button>
```

Part of the Filestructure

```
- public
       - scripts 
                - aodvAreaManagement.js --> // here is the function
                - cookies.js --> // here are also functions with the message. Which get called in index.html
       - index.html
```

Here my .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12
    },
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

How can I avoid receiving the linter message `'aodv_clear_statistics' is defined but never used.eslintno-unused-vars` while using var/function in seperate file?

Comment: `language="javascript" type="text/javascript"` is seriously not needed since 2005 or so

Comment: Also please use the submit event instead of the click event of a submit button or make it type="button"

Comment: Can you perhaps show where you define `aodv_clear_statistics`

Comment: @mplungjan ty for the advices, yes I have to rewrite a lot of the code. That is one reason why I have started to use this styleguide.

Comment: @mplungjan I posted a part of the filestructure.

Comment: Just make it unobtrusive: `document.querySelector(".aodvResetButtonAll").addEventListener("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); aodv_clear_statistics() });`